# How can I put an if statement in front of a nested list within a MudBlazor ListItem?

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I'm using a foreach loop to build a MudList. My code below throws the following error on the line that contains the if statement: "Unrecognized child component inside component MudListItem.

```
 <MudListItem ... >
     ...
      @if (nestedItems.Count > 0)
           <NestedList>
           ...
           <NestedList>
 </MudListItem>
```

Is there a way to get this to work? Everything works if I don't include the if statement, but I'm trying to prevent the user from seeing the expand icon if the list item doesn't have any nested items.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to place the if statement before the `MudListItem`:

```
@if (nestedItems.Count > 0)
{
    <MudListItem ...>
        <NestedList>
            ...
        <NestedList>
    </MudListItem>
}
else
{
    @* you can also disable the list item when nestedItems is zero *@
    <MudListItem Disabled="true" ... />
}
```